# Scope of global variable in shell script

Tags: bash, function, shell

I have a shell script like this , i am reading a file and counting the line number. 
i got logs like 1,2,3,4.. etc from inside processsNumber function

```
#!/bin/bash

number=0;
processNumber () {
    ((number++));
    echo "$number";
}

grep -E '*' readme.txt | while read -r line ; do
    processNumber "$line";
done;
echo "And at last $number";
```

But it logs 
`"And at last 0"` , but i was expecting the last line number.
Why its like that ? is it because gres reads a file a assync call hence echo has to be a callback to that.

Or is that global variable changes cannot be tracked outside the function.?

How to fix this with out changing the grep and pipe ?

NOTE: my target is not find the number of lines in the file , but to understand this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it logs  "And at last 0"

That is because you're calling `processNumber` function using a pipe which makes it execute in a sub shell not in the main shell hence in parent shell variable remains unchanged to `0`.

**UPDATE:** To avoid creating pipe (and subshell) use `for` loop like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    processNumber "$line"
done < readme.txt
```

Comment: is there a way to make callbacks in shell like javascriot callbacks ?

Comment: Shell doesn't have callback like JS has in `String#replace` but if you clarify what you want to do we can sure help. But I also request to not to change the question completely in doing do.

Comment: i need a method to how to fix this, without changing the pipe logic

Comment: ok check my updated answer for that.

Comment: Did this work out for you?

Comment: i don't want to avoid grep so i preferred solutions from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024, but ofcourse you answered my base question. Thanks

Comment: As you can see my suggested solution to part2 is also mentioned under **Workarounds** of that FAQ site. Finally if it worked out for you please consider marking the answer as accepted.